# rest_api_init is not getting invoked inside a Class

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, rest-api

When I include the code to expose custom post meta using the `rest_api_init` hook outside a specific class, it works perfectly, such as in the `functions.php` file. However, when I place the same code within a particular class, the hook doesn't seem to get invoked.

This is the code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_api_posts_meta_field' );

function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

    // register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
    register_rest_field( 'post-type-slug', 'post-meta-fields', array(
           'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
           'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
    //get the id of the post object array
    $post_id = $object['id'];

    //return the post meta
    return get_post_meta( $post_id );
}
```

And this in any class:

```
class My_REST_API {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'create_api_posts_meta_field' ) );
    }

    public function create_api_posts_meta_field() {
        register_rest_field( 'post-type-slug', 'post-meta-fields', array(
            'get_callback'    => array( $this, 'get_post_meta_for_api' ),
            'schema'          => null,
        ) );
    }

    public function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
        $post_id = $object['id'];
        return get_post_meta( $post_id );
    }
}

// Instantiate the class
new My_REST_API();
```

Comment: Where is your class code? Is it in functions.php or a separate file? If it's a separate file are you including that file into functions.php?

Comment: It's in a plugin, also even if in that plugin if I place that code outside the class it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Is this the actual code you're using in your plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is the exact code.

Comment: You could throw in some error_log() calls for trace: before and after the new line, at the start and end of __construct and at the start and end of create_api_posts_meta_field(). That will tell you that this code is being run at least. Or e.g. throw an exception from inside the constructor, or inside create_api_posts_meta_field. Ditto I can't see anything wrong with this though.